# How to be automatically redirect after firebase login?

Tags: flutter

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJ5Vrya3wCQ for implement firebase auth to my app.

All is working great except one thing. When i'm in the login screen and click on the login button, i have to restart the app to access the homepage.
That's doesn't happen when i click logout, i'm redirect to login instantly.

Here is my sign in:

```dart
  Future<String> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return "Connecté";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

main.dart

```dart
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return HomePage();
    }

    return IntroScreen();
  }
}
```

My elevated button:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  context.read<Authentication>().signIn(
                                      email: emailController.text.trim(),
                                      password: passwordController.text.trim());
                                },
                                child: Text('Se connecter'),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                          Color(0xff0d47a1)),
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                          RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(40))),
                                ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have not added a navigator to the home screen after the user logs in.

In the Elevated button's onPressed

```
onPressed: () {
       await context.read<Authentication>().signIn(
             email: emailController.text.trim(),
             password: passwordController.text.trim());
       Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
       },
```

This will work.

Comment: After check it's work great thank you, i was trying to add the navigator to authenticate.dart which is impossible.

Do you know how can i add error message ? Nothing appear if i type wrong password or something else.

Comment: I also got a problem, when you click on Sign out, you are signed out, but if i press "back" on the phone. I comeback to the HomePage..

Comment: For checking if the password is wrong you can use the FirebaseAuthException and store it in a string. After this, check if the string not empty then above the login button add a Text which will only show wrong password if  the error string is not empty. (Don't forget to use setState) (If you want the sample code i can post here)

Comment: For signing out you can use

Comment: Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('loginPage'))

Comment: Now back it work yes thank you. 
How can i include LoginPage() without name.

And yes i'm ok to get the ssample code thank you.

Comment: For a suggestion I will say use named routes in your project as the above mentioned i.e using the Function name can be bit tiring in a big project. So you need to define the named routes in the main dart file and then you can just use Navigator.pushNamed(context,"NameOfPage");

Comment: Wait, currently i redirect. But i don't check if the login is success. I got redirected everytime

Comment: I didn't get you, will you please be more specific

Comment: It's ok i finally fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is

```
bool invalid = false;
  String password;
  String error = "";
  loginUser() async {
    print(error);
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      error = e.toString();
    }
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (error.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          invalid = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "homePage");
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

And just above the login button

```
if (error.isNotEmpty)
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              if (error.split(" ").contains("password"))
                Text(
                  "Invalid Password",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
              if (error.split(" ").contains("record"))
                Text(
                  "User Does Not Exist",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
            ]),
```